# Is it possible to compare a COUNT() with a single result of a SELECT in HAVING clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, aggregation, having

I have a question on HAVING statement in SQL.

Is a query like this possible?

```
SELECT COUNT(T.IDtif) AS NumeroTifosi
FROM Tifosi T, Partita P
WHERE T.IDtif=P.Tifoso AND P.Partita=P.Idpar 
HAVING COUNT(P.Idpar) = ( SELECT COUNT(Idpar) FROM Partita
WHERE Data BETWEEN “2002101” AND ”20021231”)
```

I don't understand if it is possible to compare an aggregation function, in a HAVING statement, with a subquery that returns a single value.

Comment: Yes, you can.  You can not only do that in `HAVING`, but in `WHERE` as well.  It won't execute if more than one value is returned though.  The only difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` is that `WHERE` filters before the result set is returned, and `HAVING` filters after.

Comment: I guess a query like this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the parentheses do. You can compare a single result of a `SELECT` by turning telling SQL "it's ok, this has one value".

It could be:

```
SELECT ColA = (SELECT ColB from TableB Where Id = 1)
FROM TableA
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ColA = (SELECT ColB from TableB Where Id = 1)
```

or even with HAVING as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This query if perfectly valid.  Are you getting an error when you try to run it?

What you are doing is running a subquery once to return a count.  Then for each group, you are checking if the number of rows in that group is equal to the number returned by the subquery.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks !!!... the query is only an example created by the professor, and he told me that the Having clausole not supoprt a subquery though the subquery return a single column !.